# Convert Normal Date to TimeStamp JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

I have this date

```
Sep 7, 2019, 1:00 PM CEST
```

and want to convert it into a timestamp.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Date.parse() is returning NaN unfortunately

Comment: yes directly, it won't be useful - that's why I removed the comment - writing an answer though :)

Comment: Okay thank you for the help!

Comment: Try this, new Date("Sep 7, 2019, 1:00 PM CEST".replace('CEST', '(CEST)'))

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you if you want to write it as an answer ill give you the check

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/7986074 - this would be a helpful read.

Comment: "Sep 7, 2019, 1:00 PM CEST" **is** a timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `CEST` -> `(CEST)` and try to convert like below,

`new Date("Sep 7, 2019, 1:00 PM CEST".replace('CEST', '(CEST)'))`

Solution implemented based on this valuable [article](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-dates/). Credit goes to article author :)

Comment: Hi @casper, Can you explain reason behind changing `CEST` to `(CEST)`. It works perfectly fine but how?

Comment: it is not a proper conversion - the converted value is not equal to the original string

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I referred this article to address this problem. According to article, timezone name need to wrap in parentheses https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-dates/

Comment: Good article to understand `Date` in javascript. +1 for article

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Yeah, I've included article in the answer.

Comment: what about other timezones when app goes global??

Comment: @joyBlanks good question, here i only focused on problem asked by jrocc

Comment: yes I think using a library would be great like moment and all.

Comment: Using the built–in parser for formats not supported by ECMA-262 is strongly recommended against as the result is implementation dependent. The string should be manually parsed (maybe 3 lines of code) or a library can be used. Changing the string from one unsupported format to another doesn't change that.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is more of a pseudo-code then an exact javascript code.

The format of the string (posted by OP) is not supported natively. One of the answers used moment's `moment` function with second argument to parse the timezone i.e. `CEST` part in the querying string basically, but I found that conversion faulty too - https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1567841400&tz=Europe%2FBerlin - wondering what is `1567841400` try running this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57830429/7986074

So the code would look like this -

1. Extract the time-zone attribute from the string - i.e. `CEST` - one may use `''.substr`
2. Convert the extracted time-zone string to the UTC offset.
3. Use the UTC offset to make the date string.
4. Parse the string so made with utilities such as `Date` or `moment`

Answer (score -1):

You might need to convert your `CEST` to `GMT+0200` which contains the timezone and the offset as well.

```js
const date = new Date('Sep 7, 2019, 1:00 PM CEST'.replace('CEST', 'GMT+0200'));

console.log(date);
```

Comment: For me this produces 2019-09-07T03:00:00.000Z which is incorrect. CEST is +2, so it should produce 2019-09-07T11:00:00Z. I suspect that moment.js is ignoring the timezone abbreviation in the timestamp. Also, an answer should not rely on a library that isn't tagged or mentioned in the OP.

Comment: @RobG I tried the accepted answer which also produces 2019-09-07T03:00:00.000Z. I might be wrong by the question didn't mention that you can't use momentjs.

Comment: It's a convention of SO not to do so to prevent multiple (effectively identical) answers with different libraries. Anyway, moment.js doesn't help in this case.

Comment: @RobG thanks for enlightening those issues. I removed the moment library and also found native date requires timezone+offset to convert to utc. I updated my answer. you can have a look.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try passing that string directly into the Date constructor? But before you have to get rid of the timezone. Here is an easy example:

```
// 1. A variable with your date as a string literal
const dateStr = "Sep 7, 2019, 1:00 PM CEST"

// 2. Get rid of the timezone and use the result to instantiate a new date
const d = new Date(dateStr.slice(0,-4))

// 3. Now that you have your date instance, use getTime() method to get the timestamp
const timestamp = d.getTime()
```

Hope my answer can help you!

Comment: This likely changes the timezone of the date so that the time value is different.